# Spring Boot CORS blocks DELETE requests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, cors

Whenever I try to send request to delete endpoint with axios, I get the following error:

*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/payment_card/delete/1234123412343433' from
origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request
doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
requested resource*

Axios request is built as following :

````
      .delete(
        "http://localhost:8080/api/payment_card/delete/" +  selectedCardId ,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "**"
          },
        }
      )
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });```
My java WebSecurityConfig stays as follow:
````

```
Override protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http = http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
        http.cors().configurationSource(request -> new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());

        // Set session management to stateless
        http = http
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and();
        // Set unauthorized requests exception handler
        http = http
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new AuthException())
                .and();
        http.addFilterBefore(requestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

And in the controller, mapping is :

```
    public ResponseEntity<PaymentCard> deletePaymentCard(@PathVariable Long cardNumber) {
        PaymentCard pCard = paymentCardService.deletePaymentCard(cardNumber);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(pCard, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

I tried many solutions like adding @CrossOrigin annotation, making CorsFilter but nothing seems to help at all. Ultimately, I've changed DeleteMapping to GetMapping in my controller but
I feel like http policy can catch me to custody at any time :(
Thanks for your time and help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CorsConfiguration.applyPermitDefaultValues()` allows not all methods as one may assume, but following methods only: GET, HEAD, POST.

To allow DELETE method, you can use following code:

```
http.cors().configurationSource(c -> {
    CorsConfiguration corsCfg = new CorsConfiguration();

    // All origins, or specify the origins you need
    corsCfg.addAllowedOriginPattern( "*" );

    // If you really want to allow all methods
    corsCfg.addAllowedMethod( CorsConfiguration.ALL ); 

    // If you want to allow specific methods only
    // corsCfg.addAllowedMethod( HttpMethod.GET );     
    // corsCfg.addAllowedMethod( HttpMethod.DELETE );
    // ...
});
```

If we configure `CorsConfiguration` explicitly, I recommend not to use `applyPermitDefaultValues()`, but specify all desired methods explicitly. Then nobody will need to remember what methods exactly are enabled by `applyPermitDefaultValues()`, and such code will be easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

I could have a class that implements Filter with the following methods

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, Content-Type");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        if (HttpMethod.OPTIONS.name().equalsIgnoreCase(((HttpServletRequest) req).getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    }
}
```