# CORS ' Access-Control-Allow-Origin header' not found. React front-end/Spring boot Java Backend

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, mongodb, spring-boot

I am trying to make a DELETE request using axios on my React front-end. My API is a Java Spring-boot application. My database in run through MongoDB compass. When trying to make a DELETE request, I am getting the following error: [CORS Error upon delete request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufMbo.png)

I have tried to configure Cors on my backend but it seems to not be working:

```
package dev.xxxx.task;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig  {
    @Value("${allowed.origin}")
    private String allowedOrigin;
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer getCorsConfig ()
    {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() 
        {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry)
            {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedOrigins(allowedOrigin)
                        .allowedMethods("*")
                        .exposedHeaders("Access-Control-Allow-Origin"); // Expose the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header
                
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Front-end request:

```
const handleDelete = async (stickId)=> 
{
    
    await axios.delete(`http://localhost:8080/api/v1/sticky-note/delete/${stickId}`)
    .then((response) => {alert("Sticky deleted")})

}
```

I have tried multiple configurations on the backend, however even allowing all of the headers does not work. The front-end delete function is in a class named Sticky-note, which is an object stored in the database. This class is also responsible for rendering the sticky notes.

I have also tried using CrossOrigin(origins ="*") and other variations of that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72419923/175554 may help